# Using promises with streams in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I've refactored a simple utility to use promises. It fetches a pdf from the web and saves it to disk. It should then open the file in a pdf viewer once saved to disk. The file appears on disk and is valid, the shell command opens the OSX Preview application, but a dialog pops up complaining that the file is empty.

What's the best way to execute the shell function once the filestream has been written to disk?

```
// download a pdf and save to disk
// open pdf in osx preview for example
download_pdf()
  .then(function(path) {
    shell.exec('open ' + path).code !== 0);
  });

function download_pdf() {
  const path = '/local/some.pdf';
  const url = 'http://somewebsite/some.pdf';
  const stream = request(url);
  const write = stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path))
  return streamToPromise(stream);
}

function streamToPromise(stream) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // resolve with location of saved file
    stream.on("end", resolve(stream.dests[0].path));
    stream.on("error", reject);
  })
}
```

Comment: Is your code not working?

Comment: @Brad, clearly it isn't since *a dialog pops up complaining that the file is empty* :p

Comment: @JaromandaX The question was edited.  This makes more sense now.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In this line

```
stream.on("end", resolve(stream.dests[0].path));
```

you are executing `resolve` immediately, and the **result** of calling `resolve` (which will be undefined, because that's what `resolve` returns) is used as the argument to `stream.on` - not what you want at all, right.

`.on`'s second argument needs to be a *function*, rather than the result of calling a function

Therefore, the code needs to be

```
stream.on("end", () => resolve(stream.dests[0].path));
```

or, if you're old school:

```
stream.on("end", function () { resolve(stream.dests[0].path); });
```

<s>another old school way would be something like</s>

`stream.on("end", resolve.bind(null, stream.dests[0].path));`

No, don't do that :p see comments

Comment: Notice that the `bind` solution does evaluate `stream.dests[0].path` immediately, not when the stream ends. This might work for the static file destination, but not in general for resolving with asynchronous results.

Comment: true, I'll remove that

Answer (score 15):

#### [Stream promises API](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#streams-promises-api)

This API added in v15 provides [`stream.finished`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#streamfinishedstream-options):

```js
const { finished } = require('node:stream/promises');
const fs = require('node:fs');

const rs = fs.createReadStream('archive.tar');

async function run() {
  await finished(rs);
  console.log('Stream is done reading.');
}

run().catch(console.error);
rs.resume(); // Drain the stream.
```

https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish

Answer (score 14):

After a bunch of tries I found a solution which works fine all the time. See JSDoc comments for more info.

```
/**
 * Streams input to output and resolves only after stream has successfully ended.
 * Closes the output stream in success and error cases.
 * @param input {stream.Readable} Read from
 * @param output {stream.Writable} Write to
 * @return Promise Resolves only after the output stream is "end"ed or "finish"ed.
 */
function promisifiedPipe(input, output) {
    let ended = false;
    function end() {
        if (!ended) {
            ended = true;
            output.close && output.close();
            input.close && input.close();
            return true;
        }
    }

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        input.pipe(output);
        input.on('error', errorEnding);

        function niceEnding() {
            if (end()) resolve();
        }

        function errorEnding(error) {
            if (end()) reject(error);
        }

        output.on('finish', niceEnding);
        output.on('end', niceEnding);
        output.on('error', errorEnding);
    });
};
```

Usage example:

```
function downloadFile(req, res, next) {
  promisifiedPipe(fs.createReadStream(req.params.file), res).catch(next);
}
```

**Update.** I've published the above function as a Node module: http://npm.im/promisified-pipe

Comment: Have you add content type anywhere? Also some small improvements like end() && resolve() and end() && reject() can be applied here.

Comment: Are you referring to the "Content-Type" as the HTTP header?

Comment: Yes exactly,  because when there will be an error the response will be text otherwise pipe/file type

Comment: If you are talking about the "Usage example:" then probably you should not use  that code, it is far from being production-ready. Of course the real server would take content-type into account. Please be mindful when copying random code from StackOverflow. BUT! The main part of my answer - the `promisifiedPipe()` function - is battle tested in production. I recommend copying only it.

Answer (score 4):

The other solution can look like this:

```
const streamAsPromise = (readable) => {
  const result = []
  const w = new Writable({
    write(chunk, encoding, callback) {·
      result.push(chunk)
      callback()
    }
  })
  readable.pipe(w)
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    w.on('finish', resolve)
    w.on('error', reject)
  }).then(() => result.join(''))
}
```

and you can use it like:

```
streamAsPromise(fs.createReadStream('secrets')).then(() => console.log(res))
```

Comment: @JanakaBandara Can you add some details? in which case I should experience a problem?

Comment: Sorry, my bad! By the time I managed to get my snippet working properly, both `.on('end'` and `.on('finish'` handlers were present; but now it appears having only `.on('finish'` is sufficient (most probably I started out wrong - with `end` - and added `finish` only later)  will delete the original comment to reduce confusion

Comment: Feel free to left it. 
The actual stream handling and events around are confusing, no worries. Have a great day!

Answer (score 2):

This can be done very nicely using the promisified pipeline function. Pipeline also provides extra functionality, such as cleaning up the streams.

```
const pipeline = require('util').promisify(require( "stream" ).pipeline)

pipeline(
  request('http://somewebsite/some.pdf'),
  fs.createWriteStream('/local/some.pdf')
).then(()=>
  shell.exec('open /local/some.pdf').code !== 0)
);
```