# How to close file handle with promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, promise, async-await

I'm trying to use the `canvas` module to create a PNG file in a node.js script.

I have a file, `image.js` that handles the image creation:

```
const { createCanvas, loadImage } = require('canvas');
const fs = require('fs');

function generateImage(param1, param2) {
  const canvas = createCanvas(4096, 4096);
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  // ...
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    loadImage('base.png').then((image) => {
      ctx.drawImage(image, 40, 40, 200, 200);

      let out = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/temp.png');
      let stream = canvas.pngStream();

      stream.on('data', function (chunk) {
        out.write(chunk);
      });

      stream.on('end', function () {
        console.log('saved png');
        out.close(); // i probably don't need both, but neither seems to work properly...
        out.end();
        resolve();
      });
    });
  });
}

module.exports = generateImage;
```

When I append `generateImage('a', 'b');` at the end of this file and then run it separately (`node image.js`), it works as expected and produces my image. However, when I try to call it from a different file (in the same folder), it seems like the file handle does not close, and the image on disk is an empty file while the script is running.

`main.js` (simplified):

```
const generateImage = require('./image');
const fs = require('fs');

async function main() {
    var stats = fs.statSync("temp.png");
    console.log(stats["size"]); // output: 0, expected: > 0
}

generateImage("text", "text").then(() => main());
```

I'm new to node.js, so it's very possible that I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Is this the complete code? I think you are missing `steam.pipe(out)` in the fist snippet maybe?

Comment: Not related to your problem, but avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)! Put the `loadImage('base.png')` call outside the `new Promise`, then chain them with `then`.

Comment: `out.end` [appears to be asynchronous](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_end_chunk_encoding_callback). You will need to wait for the `close` or `finish` events on the `out` stream before resolving the promise.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44013020/using-promises-with-streams-in-node-js

Comment: @Bergi Thank you, that was the issue! My event listeners now look like the following: `stream.on('end', () => out.end());`, `out.on('close', () => resolve());`. I wasn't able to figure out how exactly I could improve my code to avoid the mentioned antipattern though. If you could post an answer with a more elegant solution, I would be glad to accept it!

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I think my function calls were fine, so I don't think it's related, but thankfully Bergi's solution worked. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: @martonbognar The linked question contains concise solution to your problem. You could use `pipe` instead of manually transfering data between streams. Then listening to `end` event on piped stream would be enough to correctly resolve the promise.

Comment: @martonbognar Basically just swap `return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    loadImage('base.png').then((image) => {` for `return loadImage('base.png').then((image) => new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {`. Or alternatively, if you want to use `async`/`await`, then it's `const image = await loadImage('base.png'); return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {…});`

Comment: out.on('finish', resolve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Bergi's advice, I needed to add another event listener for the `out` stream's `close` event, and only call `resolve()` once that is triggered. I also chained the promises instead of embedding them as in the question.

```
function generateImage(param1, param2) {
  const canvas = createCanvas(4096, 4096);
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  // ...
  return loadImage('base.png').then((image) => new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    ctx.drawImage(image, 40, 40, 200, 200);

    let out = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/temp.png');
    let stream = canvas.pngStream();

    stream.on('data', (chunk) => out.write(chunk));
    stream.on('end', () => out.end());
    out.on('close', () => resolve());  // this was missing
  }));
}
```