# Node.JS: my function corrupt a ReadStream (can't upload on S3)

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, aws-sdk

I have a function for retrive the sha256 and byte size of a ReadStream, this is my code:

```
import * as fs from 'fs';

export function streamToMeta(streamFile: fs.ReadStream): Promise<{size: number, sha256: string}> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const hash = crypto.createHash('sha256');
            hash.setEncoding('hex');
            let size = 0;
            streamFile.on('data', (chunk) => {
                size += chunk.length;
            });
            streamFile.on('end', () => {
                hash.end();
                resolve({size: size, sha256: hash.read()});
            });
            streamFile.on('error', (error) => {
                reject(error);
            });
            streamFile.pipe(hash);
        });
    }
```

The function works (return the info) but the "stream" seems corrupted or in some "strange" state and if I try to upload to s3 with:

```
    await S3.upload({Bucket: bucket, Key: key, Body: stream}).promise();
```

the upload never complete... no error, nothing... but if I don't use my function streamToMeta(), the upload works.

What I'm doing wrong into streamToMeta()?

Comment: Something is wrong,what are you hashing? Try to divide your code into two functions,hash and pipe.

Comment: Take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44013020/using-promises-with-streams-in-node-js